# Neo4j query performance tag search

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want filter messages on some words (tags).

For now only i wan't the messages that have the 2 words.

We have make a timetree so that we don't have to search in all the messages. In the best case i wan't search for one month (30 days).

In this month there are 57.371 messages.

```
PROFILE
MATCH (startleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/01/05'})
, (endleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/30/05'})
, p = shortestPath((startleaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endleaf))
UNWIND nodes(p) AS leaf
MATCH (leaf)<-[:SENDED]-(message:TS_P2000Message)
WITH distinct message
MATCH (message)-[:HAS_WORD]->(TS_Word { name:'someren'})
WITH distinct message AS message
MATCH (message)-[:HAS_WORD]->(TS_Word { name:'kruisbaan'})
WITH distinct message AS message
WITH count(message) AS results, collect(message) AS messages
UNWIND(messages) AS message
WITH results, message AS message
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
RETURN results, message

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 1065560 total db hits in 2244 ms.
```

[view profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGZLh.png)

When i wan't all the messages without the word filter the query is faster!

```
PROFILE
MATCH (startleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/01/05'})
, (endleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/30/05'})
, p = shortestPath((startleaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endleaf))
UNWIND nodes(p) AS leaf
MATCH (leaf)<-[:SENDED]-(message:TS_P2000Message)
WITH distinct message
WITH count(message) AS results, collect(message) AS messages
UNWIND(messages) AS message
WITH results, message AS message
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
RETURN results, message

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 115167 total db hits in 268 ms.
```

When we change the query for one week it is very fast, but for the best result i want one month.

So what can i do to make this query a little bit faster?

Maybe this wil help, this screen show the structure.
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6aaF.png)

EDIT:

When i not use the words and make a WHERE with regex it is faster...

```
PROFILE
MATCH (startleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/01/05'})
, (endleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/30/05'})
, p = shortestPath((startleaf)-[:NEXT*0..]->(endleaf))
UNWIND nodes(p) AS leaf
MATCH (leaf)<-[:SENDED]-(message:TS_P2000Message)
WHERE message.message =~ '(?i).*someren.*' AND message.message =~ '(?i).*kruisbaan.*'
WITH count(message) AS results, collect(message) AS messages
UNWIND(messages) AS message
WITH results, message AS message
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
RETURN results, message

Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 115186 total db hits in 342 ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query :

```
MATCH  p = shortestPath((startleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/01/05'})-[:NEXT*0..]->(endleaf:Hour{hash: '2018/04/30/05'}))
WITH NODES(p) AS dates
  MATCH (message:TS_P2000Message)-[:SENDED]->(leaf),
        (message)-[:HAS_WORD]->(TS_Word)
  WHERE leaf IN dates AND
        message.name IN ['kruisbaan', 'someren']
  WITH distinct message AS message
  WITH count(message) AS results, collect(message) AS messages
  UNWIND(messages) AS message
  WITH results, message AS message
  SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
  RETURN results, message
```

And also, can you try this query with an index on `:TS_P2000Message(name)`

Comment: Thanks for you're input, but this query takes alot of time.

`Cypher version: CYPHER 3.3, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 5657126 total db hits in 71874 ms.`

[View profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahJFv.png)

Comment: Afther a few months i was go back to this issue. I have see that the problem was with you're query. You use message.name and i have change that to word.name and add a name to (TS_Word). The result is great, the query is so fast! 

In the next days i go test even more.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the colon for the label in front of `:TS_Word`
You should have an index on `:TS_Word(name)`

I think the words sent are more restricting than your time filter.

So I would do:

```
MATCH (message:TS_P2000Message)-[:HAS_WORD]->(:TS_Word { name:'someren'}),
      (message)-[:HAS_WORD]->(:TS_Word { name:'kruisbaan'})
MATCH (leaf:Hour)<-[:SENDED]-(message)
WHERE '2018/04/01/05' <= leaf.hash <= '2018/04/30/05'
WITH count(message) AS results, collect(message) AS messages
UNWIND messages AS message
RETURN results, message
SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. (I have now update Neo4j to 3.4)

TS_Word(name) already have an unique index.

You're query is faster than mine in this case. But when we want only words with 'a2' than we have more results on the words. Than is my regex query is faster.